# Power Apps PDF() function, save PDF with Arabic letters is not working!

Tags: power-automate, flow, powerapp, pdf

I am trying to Generate PDF file from Power Apps screen, and I have achieved it using the below code:

there is shorter code to make the same using below:

```
With(
   {wPDF: PDF(SecreenName)},
   Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
      "hajjaj@hotmail.com",
      "Subject here",
      "Body here",
      {
         Attachments: 
        {
            Name: "PDFFileName.pdf",
            ContentBytes: wPDF
        }
     }
  )
)
```

The issue with this code is that it is not supporting Arabic Text, is there a way or alternative to make it work for other Arabic?

Comment: i am facing the same issue, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is listed as a known limitation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-pdf#known-limitations

[image]

Comment: did you manage to fix this? i am facing the same issue

Comment: As a workaround, replace your screen arabic label with images containing same texts

Comment: and is there a way to automate this process? i mean does power apps support converting Arabic text to image?

Comment: No, unfortunately